# sed で、セミコロンを使うとおかしくなる

Tags: sed

sed で、テキストファイルの一部分を他のテキストファイルでもって置換するスクリプトを記述していました。その際、改行だと問題なく動作するが、セミコロンを使うとエラーになる事象に遭遇しました。

これは、何が起きているのでしょうか。

スクリプト: コメントアウト部分の方を利用するとエラー(`sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched`{'`)になる

```
#!/bin/bash

cat template.txt |
    #     sed '/TMPL/{r template-value.txt; d;}'
    sed '/TMPL/{
        r template-value.txt
        d
    }'
```

参考までに、 template.txt:

```
abc
efg
TMPL
hij
```

template-value.txt:

```
zzzz
zz
zzzz
```

Comment: 関連質問 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280599/how-portable-is-it-to-use-semi-colons-as-command-separators-in-sed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GNU sed のソースコードを眺めてみると `r` コマンドの場合、改行(newline)か EOF までをファイル名として取り込んでしまうので、同じ行に別のコマンドを指定できない様です。そのため `}`(close brace) も別の行に置く必要があります。

※ `#if 0 /*XXX ZZZ 1998-09-12 kpp: added, then had second thoughts*/` となっているので、当時の GNU sed ではエラーにならなかったのかもしれません

**sed-4.2.2/sed/compile.c**

```c
/* Read a program (or a subprogram within `{' `}' pairs) in and store
   the compiled form in `*vector'.  Return a pointer to the new vector.  */
static struct vector *compile_program (struct vector *);
static struct vector *
compile_program(vector)
           :

  case 'r':
    b = read_filename();
    cur_cmd->x.fname = ck_strdup(get_buffer(b));
    free_buffer(b);
    break;

           :

/* Read in a filename for a `r', `w', or `s///w' command. */
static struct buffer *read_filename (void);
static struct buffer *
read_filename()
{
  struct buffer *b;
  int ch;

  b = init_buffer();
  ch = in_nonblank();
  while (ch != EOF && ch != '\n')
    {
#if 0 /*XXX ZZZ 1998-09-12 kpp: added, then had second thoughts*/
      if (posixicity == POSIXLY_EXTENDED)
        if (ch == ';' || ch == '#')
          {
            savchar(ch);
            break;
          }
#endif
      ch = add_then_next(b, ch);
    }
  add1_buffer(b, '\0');
  return b;
}
```

なお、bash の場合は `$'string'` 記法があるので、以下の様にも書く事ができます。

```
$ cat template.txt | sed $'/TMPL/{r template-value.txt\nd;}'
```

Comment: 当時の POSIX 仕様書は見つけられなかったのですが、http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sed.html 見ると `r` コマンドでは `<semicolon>` でコマンドをつなげて書けるとはなってないので、`#if 0` でコメントアウトされてるとは言え `posixicity == POSIXLY_EXTENDED` のチェックは意味不明ですね。

Comment: 手元に古い本も古い環境もないので忘れましたが、`<semicolon>` 自体が POSIX 拡張だったかもしれません。

Comment: [V7 Unixのsedのソース](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sed/sed0.c)をぱっと見たところでは、GNU sedと扱いは違いますが、コマンドの後に`;`があると、同じ行で再び続くコマンドの処理に進んでいるっぽく見えます（実行してないので不詳）。`r`や`i`のようにテキストを引数とするコマンドには無関係ですが。