# mac の sed で t コマンドがうまく動かない

Tags: macos, sed

foo を bar に、 bar を foo に sed で変換したいと思いました。

```
sed -e 's/foo/bar/; t; s/bar/foo/'
```

ひとまず、上記を記述してみたのですが、これは実際に実行すると、エラーになります。

```
sh-3.2$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | sed -e 's/foo/bar/; t; s/bar/foo/'
sed: 2: "s/foo/bar/; t; s/bar/foo/
": undefined label '; s/bar/foo/'
```

`man sed` を見てみたところ、以下のような記述があるので、これで動かない理由がわからないです。

```
 [2addr]t [label]
         Branch to the ``:'' function bearing the label if any substitutions
         have been made since the most recent reading of an input line or
         execution of a ``t'' function.  If no label is specified, branch to
         the end of the script.
```

#### 質問

どうして、この `t` function は動かないのでしょうか？

#### 環境

- macOS 10.14.6
- `man sed` の結果: `May 10, 2005` の BSD のものである、と書いてある。

Comment: 参考までに、Linux 5.2.8 / `sed (GNU sed) 4.7` だと意図通りに動きます

Comment: 同じくLinux環境 (sed 4.1.5)では問題無く動作します。 / 私はmacで試せる環境がありませんが、類似と思われる質問と回答が本家SOにありました - https://stackoverflow.com/q/12272065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac OSX の sed コマンドは FreeBSD 由来(もしくは NetBSD)らしいので、そちらのソースコードを眺めてみました。

**freebsd/usr.bin/sed/compile.c**

```c
static struct s_format cmd_fmts[] = {
        :
  {'s', 2, SUBST},
        :
  {'t', 2, BRANCH},
        :
};

static struct s_command **
compile_stream(struct s_command **link)
{
           :
  case BRANCH:      /* b t */
    p++;
    EATSPACE();
    if (*p == '\0')
      cmd->t = NULL;
    else
      cmd->t = duptoeol(p, "branch");
    break;

/*
 * duptoeol --
 *  Return a copy of all the characters up to \n or \0.
 */
static char *
duptoeol(char *s, const char *ctype)
```

`t` コマンドの場合、`duptoeol()` 関数でラベル文字列を読み取っています(`t` 直後の空白文字はスキップ)。そのため、以下の様にすると想定通りに動作します。

```c
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' |
  sed -e '
    s/foo/bar/
    t
    s/bar/foo/
  '
bar
foo

$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | sed -e 's/foo/bar/;t' -e 's/bar/foo/'
bar
foo
```

bash や zsh の場合は `$''` 記法を使って以下の様に書く事もできます。

```c
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | sed -e $'s/foo/bar/;t\ns/bar/foo/'
bar
foo
```

なお、`s` コマンドでは `;`(セミコロン)をコマンド文字列の終端として処理します。

**freebsd/usr.bin/sed/compile.c**

```c
case SUBST:      /* s */
  p++;
        :
  EATSPACE();
  if (*p == ';') {
    p++;
    link = &cmd->next;
    goto semicolon;
  }
  break;
```

参考までに、[sed で、セミコロンを使うとおかしくなる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/28155) を挙げておきます(こちらは GNU sed のお話です)。

Answer (score 2):

`sed` の `t` はあまり使わないコマンドなので（オイラも初めて使った）読者のために解説を入れておきます。

`t LABEL`
行読み込み成功＋直近の `t` 以後に `s` が成功していたなら `LABEL` に分岐する
`LABEL` が省略されているとき、スクリプトの末尾に分岐する

エラーメッセージを素直に読むに、標準 `sed` ではセミコロンを含めて `t` コマンドに与えるべきラベルと解釈されているようです。おそらく「セミコロンでコマンドを区切る」ことが `GNU sed` の拡張なのでしょう。

ウチの `hppa2.0w-hp-hpux11.11` の標準 `sed` では

```
$ which sed
/usr/bin/sed
$ echo foobarbaz | sed -e's/foo/bar/; t; s/bar/poo/;'
sed: The label s/foo/bar/; t; s/baz/poo/; is greater than eight characters.
$ echo foobarbaz | sed -e's/foo/bar/' -e't' -e's/baz/poo/'
barbarbaz
$ echo foxbarbaz | sed -e's/foo/bar/' -e't' -e's/baz/poo/'
foxbarpoo
$ echo foobarbaz | sed -e's/foo/bar/' -e's/baz/poo/'
barbarpoo
$
```

ということで、セミコロンでコマンドを区切るのではなく `-e` を複数回（この例では３回）指定すれば希望通りになりそう。

Comment: 補足として、どうやら「セミコロンでラベルを区切る」が GNU 拡張っぽい挙動を観測しました

Answer (score 0):

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html

^ 上記、 posix の sed の仕様を眺めていました。

> Editing commands other than **{...}**, **a**, **b**, **c**, **i**, **r**, **t**, **w**, **:**, and **#** can be followed by a `<semicolon>`, optional `<blank>` characters, and another editing command. However, when an **s** editing command is used with the **w** flag, following it with another command in this manner produces undefined results.

なので、端的に言うと、`;` セミコロンによってコマンドを終了できると明示されているのは、「複合コマンドである **{...}** であったり、コマンドそれ自体が末尾に可変長名称を取る場合」 **以外** であり、可変っぽい末尾に対しては、セミコロンは使わないのが無難である、という結論をえました。